# Must kissing number always be even?

Tags: geometry, optimization

I have been doing simulations of the kissing number problem for spheres. One thing I wondered is if there is always reflection symmetry through the central sphere?

i.e. will the optimum arrangement always be able to be arranged such that there is this reflection symmetry through the central point and hence the kissing number will always be even?

Of all the known results I think this is the case. But I can't think of a proof.

That is to say, can we simplify the problem by assuming that for each sphere that touches a point on the central sphere we can place a sphere touching it at the anti-pode? Or might this simplification miss out.

(e.g. a tetrahedral arrangement around the central sphere would be missed out, but in 3D this is not an optimal solution anyway)

A related question would be IF the kissing number is even, could it always be arranged with point-reflection symmetry?

Comment: BTW is should I ask this in stack-exchange or stack-overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were that easy with the parity of a Kissing number, why would it have taken so long to establish that $k(3)\neq 13$ and $k(4)\neq 25$? I don't see an argument that the Kissing numbers have to be even.

Comment: k(3) was solved in 1953 and K(4) in 2003. There might have been some progress in the last 20 years.

Comment: Yes, but such an elementary observation about a possible reflection symmetry would not have been overlooked.